# How to run SCDF using weblogic?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to use Weblogic instead of Tomcat to bring up SCDF locally. I am unable to find the respective guide on spring.io. Any pointer would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Cloud Data Flow builds on the Spring Boot foundation. We ship the uber-jar binary through Maven Central and/or as a container image in DockerHub or Bitnami.

You would start/run the shipped binary stand alone either in the bare-metal VMs or in a container orchestration platforms like Kubernetes.

Weblogic doesn't fit any of the functional and non-functional requirements that we expect (in SCDF) to be useful for a production setting. Simply put, you won't be able to run SCDF in Weblogic.

Please consider experimenting with SCDF using Docker Compose or Kubernetes instead.